# microservices messaging - cancel request

Tags: messaging, microservices

I am trying to get my head around micro services messaging instead of pure REST and see a lot of benefits in decoupling and using RabbitMQ or similar as dispatcher.
One thing I don't quite understand is how you would cancel a request.

For example:

Request X is composed of 4 calls to multiple micro services but micro service number 3 takes more time than expected and the whole request reaches the time out (for example 30 seconds).
I guess in the case the user will get a time out error.
But how would we cancel that request that is already in flight? I mean, say after 40 seconds micro service number 3 responds and the flow continues... the user would have received by now an error to his request.

Thanks